# Dirac Delta Evaluation of Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, expected-value, dirac-delta

I am struggling to understand what does the following expression evaluate to.

**"I am looking for general answer, not actual evaluation - i.e is dirac dealta making the integral center around h(x)? what exatly is happeneing when dirac delta is being introduced"**

$$\int g(\mathbf{x})p(x_1,y_1)\delta(x_1 - h(\mathbf x))dx_1dy_1  $$

---

It has been taken from the following context:
$${x}_{1}= \textrm{argmax} \ \mathcal{\alpha} (\mathbf{x}; I_{0})$$
$${x}_{2}= \textrm{argmax} \int \mathcal{\alpha} (\mathbf{x}; I_{1})p(y_{1}|x_{1},I_0)p(x_{1}|I_0)dx_1dy_1$$
where,
$ p(y_{1}|x_{1},I_0)$ is predictive distribution of the GP

$p(x_{1}|I_0)$ = $\delta (x_{1}-\textrm{argmax} \ \mathcal{\alpha} (\mathbf{x}; I_{0}))$

Comment: The diract delta $\delta(x)$ has the property that,

$$\int f(x)\delta(x)dx = f(0).$$

 So, if we translate the delta by $x_0$, we will get,

$$\int f(x)\delta(x-x_0)dx = \int f(\tilde{x}+x_0)\delta(\tilde{x})d\tilde{x} = f(x_0)$$

Comment: I was able to follow that, however in the above case isnt it: $$\int g(\mathbf{x})p(x_1,y_1)\delta(0)dx_1dy_1 ? $$

Comment: Also what does x~ in your equation represents?

Comment: $\tilde{x}$ is just a new variable, I didn't want to call it $x$ again.